# How to "combine" arrays

Tags: php, db2

I am query a DB2 flat file and a regular table to get information. The most current data will be coming from the not flat file. I'm putting both results into two separate arrays. Ideally I think joining the tables would have been best, but I tried and I don't know if you can join a flat file to a non flat file table. Here is array 1.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pEmpNum] => 450
            [trCode] => 1
            [pRate] => 40.00
            [pWeeksWorked] => 2.00
            [pAppr] => J014 1       
        )

)
```

And this is part of the second

```
1Array
(
[12] => Array
        (
            [empNum] => 160    
            [location] => 2         
            [payGroup] => 3
            [weeksWorked] => 02
            [defaultPay] => Y
            [unitRate] => 75.00
            [rate] => 18.67
            [appFlag] =>  
            [app1] => J014 1       
            [app2] => 
            [app3] => 
            [app4] => 
            [app5] => 
            [unit1] => .00
            [unit2] => .00
            [unit3] => .00
            [unit4] => .00
            [unit5] => .00
            [gross] => 1400.25
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [empNum] => 450        
            [location] => 2
            [payGroup] => 3
            [weeksWorked] => 00
            [defaultPay] =>  
            [unitRate] => 0.00
            [rate] => 24.63
            [appFlag] =>  
            [app1] => J014 1       
            [app2] => 
            [app3] => 
            [app4] => 
            [app5] => 
            [unit1] => .00
            [unit2] => .00
            [unit3] => .00
            [unit4] => .00
            [unit5] => .00
            [gross] => 0.00
        )

)
```

What I am trying to do is, if empnum exist in the first array I want to replace all of the info from array1 and put it into array2 for the same empnum. So in this example since empnum 450 exists in both arrays I want to replace unitRate with pRate, weeksWorked with pWeeksWorked, and app1 with pAppr. Any help or better suggestions on how to this would be great.

Comment: How big are the arrays?

Comment: It would help if your question included the platform and version of DB2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. `$array1` is the first array and `$array2` the second. You cycle through them and if `empnum` matches you swap related values. This is a 'pure' PHP solution.

```
foreach($array1 as $key1 => $data1)
{
  foreach($array2 as $key2 => $data2)
  {
    if ($data1['pEmpNum'] == $data2['empNum'])
    {
      $data2['unitRate'] = $data1['pRate'];
      $data2['weeksWorked'] = $data1['pWeeksWorked'];
      $data2['app1'] = $data1['pAppr'];
    }
  }
}
```